# app engine development task not running

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task

```
public class BackupMaker
{

    public BackupMaker(String task_handler_url, String task_queue_name,
            String task_name)
    {
        final Queue q = (task_queue_name == null) ? QueueFactory
                .getDefaultQueue() : QueueFactory.getQueue(task_queue_name);
        final TaskOptions task = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl(task_handler_url)
                .taskName(task_name);
        q.add(task);
    }
}
```

..............

```
public class BackupMakerTaskEntry extends HttpServlet
{

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Task is running !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        res.getWriter().print("hello!");
    }
}
```

..............

```
private void create_backup_task()
{
    final String task_handler_url = "/data_backup/task_entry";
    final String task_queue_name = null; // Use 'Default' queue.
    final String task_name = "Test";
    new BackupMaker(task_handler_url, task_queue_name, task_name);
}
```

The code above will create a google task app.
Problem is, the task is never being executed, on the dev server of GAE.

After adding the task, re-adding it gives an exception 'TaskAlreadyExistsException', which means the task is being added but simply won't fire.

I'm on Win7 64bit Eclipse Indigo (4.7) JDK 6u26 and newest GAE+GWT plugin/lib for Eclipse.

Any idea? Does it happen to me only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I remember in dev environment you have to run tasks manually from app console. They don't run automatically.

Comment: Is that so? Can you refer me to where it's written (just to be sure) please? And if so, how do I run from the app console? Where do I put the command? Or is it simply a matter of calling a function from the code? Thankssss!

Comment: Looks like I'm wrong: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push.html#Push_Queues_and_the_Development_Server
Maybe it worked this way in earlier versions of AppEngine.
Anyway, try starting it manually here:  http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/taskqueue

Comment: is there a way to enable the tasks to run automatically?